# FastAPI loading model.pb - SavedModel file does not exist error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, fastapi

I'm trying to load a trained model on FastAPI and try pinging it from a notebook (to mimic a frontend call). But keep getting error saying the model file doesn't exist. I'm very new to this, any advice welcome...

**Training notebook:**
`model.save('/data/model')`

Downloaded the model and put the whole folder in the FastAPI folder.

**File structure in FastAPI:**

```
>> API
  >> _pycache_
  >> model
    >> assets
    >> variables
    keras_metadata.pb
    saved_model.pb
  >> pyapi-env
  api.py
```

**api.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
...

@app.get("/predict")
def predict(test):
  ...
  model = load_model("./model/saved_model.pb")
  ...
```

**Testing notebook:**

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8000/predict"
params = {
    "test": "testing",
}
res = requests.get(url, params=params)
res.json()
```

**Error:** `OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: ./model/saved_model.pb\{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this worked for me:

```
model = load_model("./model/")
```

It seems like your code was treating "saved_model.pb" as a directory and looking for the model file inside it.

Comment: Thanks. Look back at the code I got it working with `model = load_model("project/model.h5")`. With the api.py and model.h5 both inside the same directory "project".